# Display radio button text in html with php

Tags: php, html

I am fetching an array of data from a database and displaying it to html page normally. I want to out the array value into radio button. When I print the value it displays but it's not displaying anything in radio button.

`<input type="radio" id="qid_<?php echo $row["qid"]; ?>" name="q_<?php echo $row['qid']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row["qid"]; ?>">`

I am unable find out what's wrong in this line of code.

Comment: Either put a lable for the input or add text to the end of input type like this:

`<form>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Male
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
</form>`

Comment: not working. i want to display the value from database

Comment: `<input type="radio" id="qid_<?php echo $row["qid"]; ?>" name="q_<?php echo $row['qid']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row["qid"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["qid"]; ?>`
Is this not working?

Comment: thanks MaK .. its working.. i did a silly mistake there..

Comment: i need another help now.. i want to display all the selected values..       this is code am working.. nothing displays here..               if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 
 if(isset($_POST['answer1'])){
 
 foreach($_POST as $key=>$val){
  if($key != 'submit')
        echo "$val <br/>";
 }
 }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to display the value outside the tag.
This is the syntax of radio button.

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
```

You need to display the text after the tag close

```
<input type="radio" id="qid_<?php echo $row["qid"]; ?>" name="q_<?php echo $row['qid']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row["qid"]; ?>"> <?php echo $row['qid']; ?>
```

Comment: i need another help now.. i want to display all the selected values.. this is code am working.. nothing displays here..   if(isset($_POST['submit']))  { if(isset($_POST['answer1']))  { foreach($_POST as $key=>$val)  {   if($key != 'submit') echo "$val <br/>"; }  }  }

Comment: Check whether control pass the first if condition  if(isset($_POST['submit']))  . if no, then check your submit button whether it has name parameter i.e `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="save">`